# Emacs macro works in .emacs file but not in a source file?

Tags: emacs, configuration, elisp

I have an emacs macro (global-set-key) that works perfectly fine in my .emacs file, but for whatever reason, it does not work in my .c file.

`(global-set-key "\C-c\C-d" "\C-a\C- \C-e\M-w\C-j\C-y")`

If I close and re-open my .emacs file and start messing around, this macro behaves as expected, copying a line to a line below.  However, when I open a C file the same macro simply deletes a character (it only seems to pick up on C-d).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cc-mode defines <kbd>C-c C-d</kbd> in `c-mode-base-map` to be `c-hungry-delete-forward`, which is hiding your binding at the global level.  So, the better way to solve this is to *undefine* the binding that `cc-mode` made, and you do that with the following:

```
(eval-after-load "cc-mode"
  '(define-key c-mode-base-map (kbd "C-c C-d") nil))
```

You could also do it in a hook, but I prefer `eval-after-load` because it only gets executed once.

*Note:* I determined the existing binding by opening up a file in `c-mode` and typing <kbd>C-h C-k C-c C-d</kbd> (aka <kbd>M-x describe-binding C-c C-d</kbd>), and seeing:

> C-c C-d runs the command c-hungry-delete-forward, which is an
>   interactive compiled Lisp function in `cc-cmds.el'.

This made it pretty clear that the binding was set up in (one of the) `c-mode`s, so I just opened up (or `grep`ed) the source files for `c-hungry-delete-forward` whereupon I found:

```
(define-key c-mode-base-map "\C-c\C-d"     'c-hungry-delete-forward)
```

And then the answer was straight forward.

I think it's better to *undefine* local bindings that hide the global bindings you want, rather than *redefining* them.  It's just as much work to find the problematic bindings, and this way if you want to change the function for the global binding, you only have to do it in one place.

Comment: Thanks. For future reference, how did you go about finding out what the other modes defined? Is there a file somewhere?

Comment: @Jon I've updated the answer to help with that, but it's not completely straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the C mode is removing the binding, or changing it. You can try to add it to a c-mode-hook and see if it works then. Similar to this:

```
(add-hook `c-mode-hook '(lambda ()
                         (global-set-key "\C-c\C-d" "\C-a\C- \C-e\M-w\C-j\C-y")))
```

Either `c-mode-hook` or `c-mode-common-hook`. You can also use `local-set-key` instead of the global one to apply the binding just to this buffer.

Comment: I'm really new to emacs, could you please elaborate?  How would I add to a c-mode-hook? Like so? (add-hook `c-mode-hook (global-set-key "\C-c\C-d" "\C-a\C- \C-e\M-w\C-j\C-y"))

Comment: This answer is a little confused. (1) Using `global-set-key` in a mode hook is no different to using it outside of a mode hook -- there is only one global keymap, and major/minor modes are extremely unlikely to modify it. (2) `local-set-key` does not only affect the current buffer; it affects the current buffer's *local keymap*, which in the majority of cases is usually shared by *all* buffers using the same major mode.

Comment: phils, thanks for the aclaration. As for putting it in a mode hook, it would make difference if the hook is executed *after* the mode is loaded, so the key binding supersedes that set by the mode. I'm not sure when exactly the hook is executed.

Comment: No, the new global binding does not supersede that set by the mode, because major and minor mode bindings take precedence over global bindings. See `C-h i g (elisp) Active Keymaps RET`.

Comment: In fact, Mickey wrote a superb article at his Mastering Emacs site on the subject of keybindings, so I would highly recommend reading that: http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2011/02/08/mastering-key-bindings-emacs/